# how to fix small android emulator on 4k screen

Tags: xamarin, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I I'm using 4k resulotion and I have created an emulator in avd manager but when I start emulator it shows like this picture:

[image: Android Xamarin Emulator]

How can I fix this issue and get the real size of emulator on my 4k screen.

Comment: Use the Android Device Manager (`Tools -> Android -> Android Device Manager`) to change the base device of this emulator to something more modern like Pixel 2. Or better yet, just create a new emulator here. Just an FYI, it looks like an old version of Visual Studio, it's recommended to use Visual Studio 2019 as there's a free community edition.

Comment: @JonDouglas thank you. Visual Studio 2019 fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing 2019 Visual Studio.
Thanks to @JonDouglas